# How do I show a percentage battery indicator on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, battery, screen

How do I show a percentage battery indicator on the iPhone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

iOS 4 and later natively provide a setting to toggle display of remaining battery percentage in the status bar of iPhone/iPad/iPod touch.

- **iOS 9** and later: go to Settings app → Battery → Battery Percentage.
- **iOS 4** – **iOS 8**: The option is made available under Settings app → General → Usage → Battery Percentage

Apple Knowledge base article [Show the battery percentage on your iPhone or iPad](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201102).

**iPhone X** cannot display the same in the status bar due to presence of the notch. To view remaining battery percentage on iPhone X, simply swipe-down from top-right corner of the device to open Control Centre to view the reading on-screen. A brief video with the action can be viewed in the CNET article [iPhone X: How to view your battery percentage](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/iphone-x-how-to-view-your-battery-percentage/).

**iPhone 3Gs**

[Instructions](http://justanotheriphoneblog.com/wordpress/iphone-tips/how-to-show-the-battery-percentage-indicator-on-iphone-3gs): "Settings > General > Usage – and toggle the Battery Percentage setting to On."

**iPhone 3G**

Jailbreak then install SBSettings. Select Extras & Options → Numeric Battery

Answer (score 6):

**If you have the 3GS model:**

Settings -> General -> Usage -> Battery Percentage -> ON

**If you have a jailbroken iPhone:**

Install [**SBSettings**](http://www.funkyspacemonkey.com/howto-sbsettings-iphone-os-30) in Cydia

**or**

Install asBattery, also in Cydia, using this repo:

```
http://apt.iphone-storage.de
```