# Unable to Turn off Battery Percentage Indicator

Tags: jailbreak, battery, settings

A few years ago when I had my iPhone 3GS, and wanted to see the battery displayed as a percentage (before this was implemented as a feature of iOS).  I achieved this via jailbreak.  Now my issue is this:  **I can't turn it off**.  I am several versions of phone and iOS beyond where I was when I implemented the jailbreak, unfortunately I (incorrectly) figured that when I migrated hardware this issue would resolve itself.

I am wondering is there somewhere I can go in the filesystem and remove a file or flag or something to resolve this?

The accepted answer to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5552/how-do-i-show-a-percentage-battery-indicator-on-the-iphone) goes into more detail regarding this jailbreak hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not true i have found a way to stop it without reinstalling jailbreak, well at least  for I phone 4 what you have to do it go settings> general> scroll to reset> erase all settings

Comment: Thanks, @Nick - after almost a /year/ of this question being open, you nailed it.  The funny part is, I had to a settings reset on my girlfriend's iPhone not 2 weeks ago to fix keyboard sluggishness.  Shame on me for not trying this myself.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that if you're "several versions of phone and iOS beyond where" you were when you did this, then you are likely not jailbroken anymore? Because they introduced the percentage as an option and is configurable in 
Settings >> General >> Usage >> Battery Percentage (last option for me).

If you're still jailbroken and you have this option off already, then I'm sorry, I can't help you there. Good luck

Comment: That's correct, I am no longer jailbroken and the battery percentage indicator persists regardless of the setting.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need to do. Re-jailbreak and download SBS Settings. Turn off battery percentage in SBS Settings. Then do restore in Itunes.It will then unjailbreak your iphone and leave the percentage in the status bar off. You can then turn it on or off to your preference. So annoying..I am not jailbreaking any more.